# Switching between regular and fat jars with Gradle script

Tags: gradle, jar, executable-jar

I have a tiny java project using gradle, and would like to be able to choose between generating a regular jar and a fat jar.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'com.myTest'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If I use the above script to build, i will get a fat jar. In order for me to get a jar, i will need to remove the "jar" block. What do I need to do so that I can switch between the two from the command line?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new task for the fatJar task like below,

```
task fatJar(type: org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar, group: "build") {

manifest {
    attributes(
        'Main-Class': 'com.myTest'
    )
}
baseName(project.name.concat("-fatJar"))
from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.directory ? it : zipTree(it) 
 }
}
```

Refer: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: Just found a problem when I tried to run the jar from command line. I found that the binary of my own class is actually missing from the jar...

Comment: Found out that you can't leave out "with jar" in the task. Thanks!